# Character counter in jQuery for ajax loaded text area?

Tags: jquery

Character counting has been covered a lot - what I can't find out is how to get it to count dynamically loaded content.

I'm using [jqEasy Character Counter](http://web.archive.org/web/20150317063551/http://www.jqeasy.com/jquery-character-counter) which is a nice plugin for jQuery. It works beautifully with input/textareas on the same page but if I try and load in content via an ajax call it stops working. Here is my code so far :

This is the char counter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".countable").jqEasyCounter({
        'maxChars': 250,
        'maxCharsWarning': 230,
        'msgFontSize': '11px',
        'msgFontColor': '#000',
        'msgFontFamily': 'Verdana',
        'msgTextAlign': 'right',
        'msgWarningColor': '#F00',
        'msgAppendMethod': 'insertAfter'                
    });
});
```

This is the ajax call that loads the dynamic content :

```
    $(document).on("change", "#sitedrop_id", function(event){   
  $.post(
   'load_site.php',
    $("#siteselectform").serialize(),
    function(data){
      $("#sitedata").html(data)
    }
  );
  return false;
  });
```

This is one of the text areas of the form loaded in from another page :

```
<p>
    <label for="headermsg_id" style="width:150px">Heading</label><textarea
class="countable" rows="4" cols="55" name="headermsg" id="headermsg_id"
style="resize: none; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
</textarea>
</p>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and I've tried `$(document).on("change","#headermsg_id",function(event){` then the counter but thats not working either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-initialize the counter plugin after replacing your content with the ajax loaded stuff, e.g.:

```
var initCounter = function () {
    $(".countable").jqEasyCounter({
        'maxChars': 250,
        'maxCharsWarning': 230,
        'msgFontSize': '11px',
        'msgFontColor': '#000',
        'msgFontFamily': 'Verdana',
        'msgTextAlign': 'right',
        'msgWarningColor': '#F00',
        'msgAppendMethod': 'insertAfter'                
    });
};


$.post({
    ...
    function(data){
      $("#sitedata").html(data);
      initCounter();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with ID *sitedata* in your posted code. Try replacing

```
$("#sitedata").html(data)
```

with

```
$("#headermsg_id").html(data)
```

because this is the only element you've posted which has the class *countable* and only those elements gets counted because you've initialized the easyCounter with the selector ".countable"

Comment: #sitedata is where the ajax content is being loaded - and the textarea has the class `countable`.

Comment: Yes, but either the element *#sitedata* has to get the class *countable* or you have to put the text in the textarea with this class. Alternatively you could extend you selector for initializing the plugin: $(".countable, #sitedata").jqEasyCounter({...})